# How to Check if a Point is in KML Polygon (GIS Shapefile)

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I have an Overlay KML Polygon exported from a Shapefile, is there any way I can find weather a point is in that polygon(KML) or not?
I know this is possible when we create polygon trough Google map api like

```
var polygon = new google.maps.Polygon([], "#000000", 1, 1, "#336699", 0.3);
```

But how we can do this with KML overlays?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have 2 options with KML:

1. use a third party parser like [geoxml3](https://code.google.com/p/geoxml3/) or [geoxml-v3](https://code.google.com/p/geoxml-v3/) to render your KML as native Google Maps API v3 polygons, then use the way you know how. [example using geoxml3](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_collection-map2e.html)
2. import your KML into a FusionTable, and use the ST_INTERSECTS to check for the intersection of your Polygon with a small circle around your point [example using FusionTables](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_collection-map2e_FT.html). Note with FusionTables you can directly import shapefiles using [shpescape.com](http://www.shpescape.com/)