# Is there an easy way to see if my Lat/Lng falls within a KML file?

Tags: php, wordpress, google-maps, kml

Basically I have a client that has about 1-5 KML files that will be uploaded to his website and he has a form that users will enter their address to see if they fall within any of those KML file locations.

So far I've been able to get the Lat/Lng from the Address that is entered and I can loop through the KML files themselves but I haven't been able to find a way, yet, to determine if the Lat/Lng I have is within any of the KML files.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Check if a Point is in KML Polygon (GIS Shapefile)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15264735/how-to-check-if-a-point-is-in-kml-polygon-gis-shapefile)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the KML files contain polygons (and not points or lines), then this sounds like a basic "point in polygon" type of GIS analysis.  You'll need to find a library that can do that kind of analysis function in whatever environment you're running the code in.