# Find polygon for place in KML

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, kml

**NOTE**: Please make sure you read my updates at the bottom!!

---

I have a KML file that I load 'onto' a Google Map; I also have a searchbox where users can search for a city. When the city is found I place a marker which, in most (if not all) cases should fall in one of the polygons defined in the KML.

I can click a polygon and it shows an info-popup with the areacode for that area; however: when a marker is placed I would like to have this info-popup shown *automatically* (and possibly other(s) that are shown before placing the marker hidden).

I have looked over the [Maps V3 documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/) but was unable to find anything. Is this possible?

You can view the project at http://netnummer.robiii.me, the source can be found at https://github.com/RobThree/NetnummersNL

The relevant (snippet of) code is:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function () {
    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
    if (!place.geometry)
        return;

    // Remove any existing markers
    for (var i = 0, marker; marker = markers[i]; i++)
        marker.setMap(null);
    markers = [];

    // Create a marker for place.
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        icon: image,
        title: place.name,
        position: place.geometry.location
    });
    markers.push(marker);

    // ... Here I should figure out in which polygon the marker is positioned
    // ... and preferrably open/display the info-window which is shown when a
    // ... polygon is clicked.

    // Scroll (pan) to marker
    map.panTo(place.geometry.location);
});
```

Also, as a side-question: `autocomplete.getPlace();` always returns an object; what is the best way to find out if the object is an actual (useful) place? When I search for `xxxx` for example, `getPlace()` returns `Object {name: "xxxx"}`, an actual result (like searching for `Amsterdam`) returns `Object {address_components: Array[4], adr_address: "<span class="locality">Amsterdam</span>, <span class="country-name">Nederland</span>", …}`. I currently use `if (!place.geometry)` to find out if the place is useful / an actual place; however I guess there's a better way ('best practice'?) to do this?

---

**Edit 1**: just stumbled across [With Google Maps API V3, determine if a marker is inside a KML Layer boundary](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10323700/215042). Currently looking into it. However, I *should* probably note that the KML is hosted by a 3rd party and updated at will by them; as I use static site hosting I prefer not to have a separate process to extract the coordinates from polygons from the KML file. I prefer to "read" the KML (in)directly.

---

**Edit 2**: I moved [from (direct) KML](https://github.com/RobThree/NetnummersNL/blob/901d73417942d756f4168f60ffb6e267d3962338/index.htm) to [a FusionTables based solution](https://github.com/RobThree/NetnummersNL/blob/0b4274001f7af6c625983e072959bf704cd794c3/index.htm). I can now "highlight" polygons where the place is in. Now all I (still) need is a way to figure out how to show it's InfoWindow. I'll look into that tomorrow; it seems I need to query (again) [into a DataTable or something](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/samples/gviz_datatable) and get the label info that way.

---

**Edit 3**: [Solved](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31174176/215042)!

Comment: You mean something like [this (geoxml3) example](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_collection-map2e.html) or [this (FusionTables) example](http://www.geocodezip.com/webknows_net_schoolboundarynewC.html)

Comment: Both examples don't seem to be using KML data? Or am I mistaken?

Comment: "hosted by a 3rd party and updated at will" will be an issue for both of the examples in my previous comment. The first example uses a KML file (it has an .xml extension, but is KML), the second uses KML imported into FusionTables.  geoxml3 is subject to the same domain restriction, so the KML would have to be accessed through a proxy (a problem on a "static site hosting" account).  Although not sure how you are planning on processing the KML file from a 3rd party site without active content on your site.

Comment: The geoXML3 solution results in an (expected) `XMLHttpRequest cannot load 'https://…'. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`. I could host the KML on my own host (and keep a copy up to date). Will look into that tomorrow; time for bed :-) Thanks for the help so far!

Answer (score 0):

I should've been in bed by now (see [edits](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31171899/215042) and [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31171899/find-polygon-for-place-in-kml#comment50352090_31171899)) but hey... I just don't let go that easily...

So here's what I did:

1. [Move from (direct) KML to Fusion Tables](https://github.com/RobThree/NetnummersNL/commit/0b4274001f7af6c625983e072959bf704cd794c3) ([Resulting html](https://github.com/RobThree/NetnummersNL/blob/0b4274001f7af6c625983e072959bf704cd794c3/index.htm))
2. [Fire off an extra query using Google Visualization's datatables](https://github.com/RobThree/NetnummersNL/commit/4f5c2b6cc4d6b26c6ebebc3b09e41d8d4631e9b8) to get the data I want for the specific region ([Resulting html](https://github.com/RobThree/NetnummersNL/blob/4f5c2b6cc4d6b26c6ebebc3b09e41d8d4631e9b8/index.htm))
3. [Use the `place` variable I already had for lat/lng and name](https://github.com/RobThree/NetnummersNL/blob/4f5c2b6cc4d6b26c6ebebc3b09e41d8d4631e9b8/index.htm#L148) and show infowindow
4. ...
5. [Profit](https://github.com/RobThree/NetnummersNL/tree/9a65f767b79bb1750baf591528fc9921e742159c)!

I purposely linked above links to specific diffs or files of a specific version so later changes/updates won't mess with this answer. It's a bit too much to post all specifics in this post but I hope this helps someone.

The final result can be seen [here](http://netnummer.robiii.me/).